# Is it possible to breed Authentic Sinistea/Polteageist?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

So Polteageist has two forms: Authentic (evolved with Chipped Pot) and Fake (with Cracked Pot), depending if it has some sort of mark, as seen when Dynamaxing, apparently.

Now, if I have an authentic Polteageist and I breed it with a Ditto, would that make all of its children (or at least, has a chance of being) authentic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just caught an authentic Sinistea yesterday and have been breeding it with a Ditto. So far, I’ve hatched 30 eggs, and all of them have been phony. I have not found definitive evidence, so I plan to continue the hunt. I hope this helps!